# Python merging mostly duplicated rows, split column to other column

Tags: python, pandas

input data is dataframe

```
[
name1 name2 data1  data2
a     x      1      ""
a     y      2      "" 
b     x      3      ""
b     y      4      ""
a     x      5      ""
a     y      6      "" 
b     x      7      ""
b     y      8      ""
]
```

what I want is

```
[
name1 name2 data1  data2
a     x      1      5
a     y      2      6 
b     x      3      7
b     y      4      8
]
```

for same [name1,name2], move data1 to data2. How can I do this with python? with pandas?
similar topics "Python Pandas — merging mostly duplicated rows", but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with columns `name1` and `Series` created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html).

Last rename columns and create columns from `index` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['name1','name2', df.groupby(['name1','name2']).cumcount()])['data1'] \
       .unstack().rename(columns = lambda x: 'data' + str(x + 1)).reset_index()
print (df)
  name1 name2  data1  data2
0     a     x      1      5
1     a     y      2      6
2     b     x      3      7
3     b     y      4      8
```

Another solution is create `list` and then new `df` by `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['name1','name2'])['data1'].apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(), index=df1.index)
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: 'data' + str(x + 1)).reset_index()
print (df)
  name1 name2  data1  data2
0     a     x      1      5
1     a     y      2      6
2     b     x      3      7
3     b     y      4      8
```

Comment: Cannot find a simple way to explode lists... giving up... +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ don't give up!

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
[d[(n1, n2)].append(d1) for n1, n2, d1, d2 in df.values];

pd.DataFrame(
    d, [1, 2]
).T.add_prefix('data').rename_axis(['name1', 'name2']).reset_index()

  name1 name2  data1  data2
0     a     x      1      5
1     a     y      2      6
2     b     x      3      7
3     b     y      4      8
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `numba`

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def plc(f, v):
    m = np.bincount(f).max()
    n = f.max() + 1
    a = np.arange(n * m).reshape(n, m) * 0
    j = np.arange(n) * 0
    for x, y in zip(f, v):
        a[x, j[x]] = y
        j[x] += 1
    return a

f, u = pd.Series(zip(df.name1.values, df.name2.values)).factorize()

new = np.column_stack([np.array(u.tolist()), plc(f, df.data1.values)])

pd.DataFrame(new, columns='name1 name2 data1 data2'.split())

  name1 name2 data1 data2
0     a     x     1     5
1     a     y     2     6
2     b     x     3     7
3     b     y     4     8
```

---

**Timing**
*small data*

```
%%timeit
f, u = pd.Series(zip(df.name1.values, df.name2.values)).factorize()

new = np.column_stack([np.array(u.tolist()), plc(f, df.data1.values)])

pd.DataFrame(new, columns='name1 name2 data1 data2'.split())

###############################################################

%%timeit 
d = defaultdict(list)
[d[(n1, n2)].append(d1) for n1, n2, d1, d2 in df.values];

pd.DataFrame(d, [1, 2]).T.add_prefix('data').rename_axis(['name1', 'name2']).reset_index()

###############################################################

%%timeit
df1 = df.groupby(['name1','name2'])['data1'].apply(list)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(), index=df1.index)
df2.rename(columns = lambda x: 'data' + str(x + 1)).reset_index()

#--------------------------------------------------------------

1000 loops, best of 3: 400 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.23 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.82 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is nice :) How would it fare in a speed test?

Comment: Over this small data set: mine clocks in at `2.22 ms` vs. `2.87 ms`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ added another one (-:

Comment: Wow... nice! Didn't know about numba. Sounds fancy.